# remove a fixed interval of value from a column with type string - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

i'm learning how to use map in pandas.

i got a df with a column like this:

```
   score
0  7.0/10
1  1.0/10
2  8.3/10
3  nan
4  4.5/10
```

with type str if is not nan and type float if it is.
i want to have a serie that look like that

```
   score
0   7.0
1   1.0
2   8.3
3   nan
4   4.5
```

with all type float.
i tried to use map and split and i created the column score as:

```
      score
0  ['7.0','10']
1  ['1.0','10']
2  ['8.3','10']
3  [nan]
4  ['4.5','10']
```

so i tought that i can split those list in two columns and keep just the first, but i cannot do that because i have some list (the nan ones) with just one element.

i think that with map i can tell python to just keep the [0:4] values of each string. but i don't know how to write that down.

hope you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `.str.split`:

```py
df.score = df.score.str.split("/").str[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  score
0   7.0
1   1.0
2   8.3
3   NaN
4   4.5
```

Comment: thank you so much, it worked.
can i ask you where the documentation for that is? i feel really dumb

Comment: @GiudittaDavini Here is [link to documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) Glad to help :)